# Timeout when using Mockgoose/Mongoose save/create with Mocha and Chai-Expect

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, mockgoose

I am getting Timeout running Unit Tests with `Mocha`, `Chai` and `Mockgoose`

I have a function `Assessment.NewAssessment(assessmentDetails)` that will save the assessment in the DB.

**NOTE**: `Assessment.NewAssessment returns a promise (It is an async function)

Here is what I did so far:

```
require('assert');
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
let expect = chai.expect;
let Assessment = require('../models/Assessment');
let CustomError = require('../CustomError');

let mongoose = new (require('mongoose').Mongoose)();
let Mockgoose = require('mockgoose').Mockgoose;
let mockgoose = new Mockgoose(mongoose);

before(function (done) {
    mockgoose.prepareStorage().then(async function () {
        mongoose.connect(
            'mongodb://127.0.0.1/' + process.env.DB_NAME + '_test?replicaSet=rs0',
            {useNewUrlParser: true},
            function (err) {
                done(err);
            });
    });
});

describe('Class Assessment', function () {
    describe('Function GetAll', function () {
        it('Throw an error with code 400 for non-object parameters', () => {
            return expect(Assessment.GetAll('test'))
                .to.be.eventually.rejectedWith(CustomError)
                .and.have.property('code', 400);
        });

        it('Successfully creating an assessment', async () => {
            let assessmentDetails = {
                name: 'test',
                createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            };
            let assessment = await Assessment.NewAssessment(assessmentDetails)

            return expect(assessment).to.be.an('object');
        });
    });
});
```

In `Assessment.js`:

```
static async NewAssessment(assessmentDetails) {
    if (!assessmentDetails || typeof assessmentDetails !== 'object') {
        throw new CustomError('assessmentDetails is not defined.', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return await new Assessment(assessmentDetails).save();
}
```

The output of running `mocha --timeout 120000` is:

```
Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where does it stop? At which step?

Comment: First test passes correctly, it stops at the second test, function call `Assessment.NewAssessment(assessmentDetails)`

Comment: I can not execute your code and test it, so as an untested suggestion I would say try to remove `return` from that function and call `done()` after the `expect` statement. **Plus** are you returning promise from `NewAssessment`?

Comment: It is an async function, I'll add it in the question

Comment: I tried using `done()` same, timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but with this:

```
it('Successfully creating an assessment', async () => {
    let assessmentDetails = {
        name: 'test',
        createdBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    };

    return expect(Assessment.NewAssessment(assessmentDetails))
        .to.be.eventually.an('object');
);
```

It is working fine.